# I'm stuck calculating the time complexity of nested for loops

Tags: java, time-complexity, nested-loops

I've been trying to determine the time complexity of nested for loops 
here is the problem:

[image]

I've done some work , but yet can't reach a decisive answer. I've reached a sequence of(log(100)+ log(200)+....log(n/4)), yet can't determine the sum of it.

[image]

### Update

I have an idea, I'm uploading it it as  a picture, please tell me if it's correct:

[image]

Comment: Please add your code to the post and format it rather than posting images of code.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, what you have here is a *series*. To be able to calculate the sum, you should write the series in a uniform notation and either calculate the sum yourself or use some tool (such as Wolfram Alpha) to compute the series for you.

In this case, the format is: sum from i = 1 to (n/400) of log(100 * i).

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+log_2(100+*+i),+i+%3D+1+to+n%2F400

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be over thinking it. You have two nested loops. Clearly the outer one is `O(n)`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n / 4; i += 100)
```

It has a low constant factor, a constant factor that is making it faster, but that does not mean that it is not `O(n)`

In the inner loop

```
for (int j = 1; j < i; j *= 2)
```

`j` keeps doubling until it is larger than `i` so it runs *k* times if *k* is the first power of two greater than `i`, so `2^k ≥ i`, or *k* is the base-2 log of `i`. That means this loop is O(log n) since `i` is linearly related to `n`. Thus the whole thing is O(n log n)